# Once a change has been verified and integrated, how long until it is searchable?

Tags: here-api

My home address was missing from the Here maps so I added it and the rest of my newly developed neighborhood via the map creator at mapcreator.here.com. However, even though the changes have been accepted and integrated, my address is still not populating in the search autocomplete. The main issue is that Amazon does not get the correct pin for my address. Packages I attempt to have delivered to my address go to a completely different city 15 minutes away. I thought adding my address to the map creator would resolve the issue but the issue persists even after my changes were integrated.

I was expecting that, once the changes were integrated, I'd be able to search for my address both in Map Creator and on Amazon. Hopefully, this would allow Amazon to pin the correct location and deliver my packages to the right address.

Does it take a certain amount of time for addresses verified and integrated via the map creator to appear in results for the search/autocomplete api?